# How to Inner Join a many to one on Like condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, join

I'm tyring to fix this query, I think I'm on the right track but I am still not sure what is wrong with my query because it is not returning anything.

Here is the setup.

TableA has this values:

Field: itemnumber

- S3
- S2
- S1
- A1

TableB

Field: itemoptions

- RK-S3
- RE-S3
- LO-S1
- SE-S1
- AE-A1
- JA-S2

Currently the problem is that both tables doesn't have any relationship aside from the itemnumber is the last part of itemoption

My Goal is to combine the 2 fields of those table to generate something like

- S3 | RK-S3
- S3 | RE-S3
- S1 | LO-S1
- S1 | SE-S1
- A1 | AE-A1
- S2 | JA-S2

Here is my SQL Code that I'm trying to make it work

```
SELECT itemoptions,itemnumber
FROM TableB
JOIN (SELECT Distinct(itemnumber)
FROM 
       TableA
WHERE
       List_ID = 3
)
ON itemoptions LIKE concat('%', itemnumber)
```

Edit: Thanks for poiting out the concat, I fix the query. I tried doing that on my original query but I'm not getting any results. Thanks for the fast replies, I'm trying all the suggested options

Comment: String concatenation in MySQL uses the `CONCAT()` function, not `+`.

Comment: Your best option is to normalize and fix the schema and split `itemoptions` in two columns. That would also allow for foreign key constraints and indexes to support the join.

Comment: Concat is changed. Unfortunately normalizing and fixing the schema is not an option for this one. The query I'm doing is just for extracting specific data, I'm hoping their is a good reason why they decided to make it like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string concatenation function is `CONCAT()`. `+` is only used for addition.

```
SELECT itemnumber, itemoptions
FROM TableB
JOIN TableA ON itemoptions LIKE CONCAT('%', itemnumber)
WHERE List_ID = 3
```

You don't need a subquery, you can put the `WHERE` condition in the main query.

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hQRPac3mATgZUszFoqEUkg/0)

Comment: This also didn't return any result, this is similar to my first setup that is why I decided to do subquery.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar, this is great example. I'm going to  trace the problem on my query on why this method is not working. Will give an update later

Comment: It is a bit bizzarre, I tried playing around it and it kinda works if I do this
SELECT itemnumber, itemoptions
FROM TableB
JOIN TableA ON itemoptions LIKE CONCAT('%', 'S3')
WHERE List_ID = 3 AND itemnumber = 'S3'     |  Which doesnt make any sense for mle (In this scenario only the S3 is return)

Comment: I should have thought this sooner, the problem is spaces in itemnumber

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses `concat()` rather than `+` for string concatenation (the latter stands for numeric addition).

Consider:

```
select ta.itemnumber, tb.itemoptions
from tablea ta
inner join tableb tb on tb.itemoptions like concat('%-', ta.itemnumber)
```

Comment: I tried just changing the concat, but I got 0 result